# Python class polymorphism

Tags: python, polymorphism, class-method

I am practicing polymorphism and the following code returns error

```
class Animal:
    def talk(self, something):
        print(something)

class Dog(Animal):
    def talk(self):
        super().talk("woof woof")

Bonny = Dog
Bonny.talk()
```

```
TypeError: talk() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

According to what I learned Bonny should be the self argument so why self is missing?

Comment: Here's a hint, courtesy of my IDE: _Signature of method 'Dog.talk()' does not match signature of base method in class 'Animal'_ Also, try executing `print(type(Dog), type(Dog()))`. This example is a bit strange overall.

Comment: `Bonny = Dog()` to Instantiate the object.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing some brackets at `Bonny = Dog`.

```
class Animal:
    def talk(self, something):
        print(something)

class Dog(Animal):
    def talk(self):
        super().talk("woof woof")

Bonny = Dog()
Bonny.talk()
```

### EDIT

Since this is my top voted answer at the moment, and still has some activity, and it clearly lacks some explanation, I would like to add some.

```
Bonny = Dog
```

Means, `Bonny` is a reference to the `Dog` class. It is callable, and would the the instance of `Dog`. `Bonny` won't be a type.

```
Bonny = Dog()
```

If you would like to call the object like above, you should add the brackets. That means you call the object, and referring to it. `Bonny` will be a reference.

Also references to object should be lowercase.

```
bonny = Dog()
```

Second thing. Since your objects indicates they may contain data corresponding to each object of the same type (2 or more Dog objects), so there is a need for a `constructor`.

```
class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(self)
        self.name = name

    def talk(self):
        super().talk("woof woof my name is {}".format(self.name))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This way you can name your dog, make him say his name, and on `print(bonny)`, also print his name using the `__str__` method. But also you need to call the super's (in this case the `Animal` objects) init function, using the `super` function, used by the OP.

Class inheritence isn't the easiest thing in Python, since it is not a strongly OO language. But classes are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You did not initialize an object, you just created a copy of your `Dog` class with name `Bonny`. You can see the difference between `Dog()` and `Dog` by printing them.

```py
class Animal():
    pass

print(Animal)   # the result is <class '__main__.Animal'>

print(Animal()) # the result is <__main__.Animal object at 0x037D6A50>
```

first line is referring to a class which is named `Animal` but the second line is an object of class `Animal`. so if you want to create an object of a class you have to initialize the class (just as the second form).
your correct code will be this:

```py
class Animal:
    def talk(self, something):
        print(something)

class Dog(Animal):
    def talk(self):
        super().talk("woof woof")

bonny = Dog()
bonny.talk()
```

also according to [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) it's standard to name objects in lowercase.